# Auto-generate main method from referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, compiler-errors, compilation

I am editing my question I think it is a little confusing and it does not explain what my intent is.

### Edit:

My goal is that when my `HelloWorld` application references `MyClassLibrary` my code does not compile so that I ensure to initialize some code prior to running the main method. **Kind of like a constructor of a class. When I reference `MyClassLibrary` I will like to run some code in there before running the main method of my `HelloWorld` application.** NUnit has a similar functionality. When my `HelloWorld` application references NUnit I get the error: `Error CS0017 Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.` As @Alex pointed out that Main method that NUnit creates is auto-generated. I will like to auto-generate a main method with some custom code. How can I do that from `MyClassLibrary` without doing anything on my `HelloWorld` application just like NUnit does it?

---

### OLD Question:

I want to perform the same behavior that `NUnit` tests perform that it prevents using a `Main` method. In this case the error that I need is a good thing. Let me explain what I mean.

1. I create a hello world application targeting the `.net core`

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Code file: (default hello world c# code)

2. If I then run that application it runs fine
3. Add a reference to `NUnit` and my project file now contains.

.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

4. When I try to compile the project I get the error:

> Error CS0017  Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

**That means that there is another `Main` method. That method is probably located on the `NUnit` nuget package I am referencing. This is the error I am trying to replicate!.**

---

**Now this is how I try to replicate the same error:**

1. I remove the `NUnit` nugget package having no references to `NUnit` on my hello world application.
2. Create a Project `ClassLibrary1` with the following code:

.

```
public class MyLib
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fooooo");
        // do something
    }
}
```

3. Have my hello world application reference that project:

[image]

**When I compile I get no errors even though there are 2 `Main` methods!**

How does `NUnit` manages to prevent using a `Main` method? How can I replicate the same behavior? I want to create an assembly that when referenced it prevents executing the `Main` method.

Comment: This is not surprising to me. You can't test exe files with a unit testing framework - the testing framework _is_ the application when testing.

Comment: I do not need to Test. I need to prevent my application from having a Main method @500-InternalServerError

Comment: Depends on the project type, a class library will not execute any main methods. But something like a console project will require one entry point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- It's just `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` making build fail.
- Adding `<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>` into `<PropertyGroup>` makes it compile and work anyway.
- But adding another class with `static void Main` to the application makes build fail again regardless `<GenerateProgramFile>`.
- In your example build fails because `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` adds some auto-generated code to your application before compilation. That code is in `...\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\16.2.0\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs`. It's a class with another `Main`:

---

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated. </auto-generated>
using System;
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode]
class AutoGeneratedProgram {static void Main(string[] args){}}
```

---

> **BTW:** it's **absolutely legal** to have `Main` method in another assembly. You just cannot have 2 `Main`s in one **exe**. But you can have **any** number of them in **dll** like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Main() { }

    public static void Main(string[] args) { }
}

public class Class2
{
    public static void Main() { }

    public static void Main(string[] args) { }
}
```

> It compiles.

---

**Update:**

I found the solution. **It's all about installing `nuget`, not just adding a reference.**

1. Create a `.NET Core Class Library` and name it `MyCoreLib`.
2. Add `MyCoreClass`.

---

```
namespace MyCoreLib
{
    public static class MyCoreClass
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Initialized from 'MyCoreLib'");
        }
    }
}
```

---

3. Build the library.
4. Create the following file structure:

---

```
├───nuget
└───src
    │   MyCoreLib.nuspec
    │
    ├───build
    │   └───netcoreapp2.1
    │           ForcedEntryPoint.cs
    │           MyCoreLib.targets
    │
    └───lib
        └───netcoreapp2.1
                MyCoreLib.dll
```

MyCoreLib.nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyCoreLib</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>MyCoreLib</authors>
    <owners>MyCoreLib</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Some description here</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.1" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

ForcedEntryPoint.cs

```
//╔════════════════════════════════════╗
//║ This code was added automatically. ║
//║    Do not change or remove it.     ║
//╚════════════════════════════════════╝
public static class ForcedEntryPoint
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyCoreLib.MyCoreClass.Initialize();
    }
}
```

MyCoreLib.targets

```
<Project InitialTargets="ForceEntryPoint" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ForcedEntryPoint Condition="'$(ForcedEntryPoint)' == ''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ForcedEntryPoint$(DefaultLanguageSourceExtension)</ForcedEntryPoint>
    <ForceEntryPoint Condition="'$(ForceEntryPoint)' == ''">true</ForceEntryPoint>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="ForceEntryPoint" Condition="'$(ForceEntryPoint)' == 'true'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="$(ForcedEntryPoint)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

---

4. Use [NuGet Commandline](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) to build  a package like this:

---

```
D:\nugetwalkthrough\nuget>D:\nugetwalkthrough\nuget.exe pack D:\nugetwalkthrough\src\MyCoreLib.nuspec
```

---

5. Create a `.NET Core Console App` and make sure it works.
6. Install the created package.
7. Try to run the application and get error:

   > CS0017    Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.
8. Remove the `Main` method from the application, run it and see it prints `Initialized from 'MyCoreLib'`.
9. Put the `Main` method back to the application and change the project file so that `<PropertyGroup>` contains `<ForceEntryPoint>false</ForceEntryPoint>`
10. Now it compiles and prints `Hello World!` from its own `Main` method.
11. Changing `<ForceEntryPoint>` to `true` makes it use another entry point (not that one of the application) again.

Comment: Yes Alex I want to add some initialization code before my Main method runs. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I added a T4 template on my referenced Assembly and that code creates a Main method but on the referenced Assembly. **I need for that Main method to be on my main executable. How can I do that just like NUnit does it?** When creating that T4 template my code still compiles. I want to ensure it does not compile so that I remember that I have to run some initialization code

Comment: @TonoNam, great! That auto-generated calss with another `Main` is added to your console appliction, not  referenced assembly. That's why the application doesn't compile. It's a kind of the package trick. I'll try to inspect how it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198250/discussion-between-tono-nam-and-alex).

Comment: Alex I have to wait one day to award you the bounty. I will accept the bounty on Monday once stack overflow lets me. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @TonoNam, OK. Looks like the question is valuable)

Answer (score 3):

I  think you  should learn how to make multiple project under same solution.
So helloworld is main project. 
Then create new test project helloworld.test as test project use Add a reference to NUnit there.
now all will work fine  you can change your start up project to helloworld.test and debug or run it from visual studio or command line.
Anyway I never saw a test  project inside main project in professional coding. May be for testing we  comment main method and run test case.
Test project is also Executable.